# Problems in creating a new column and looping a formula from first column. code i made and error message is displayed below.

Tags: r

> str(st1)
>   'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ st: num  1 2 3 4
>   st1$z=" "
>   summary(st1)
>          st            z
>    Min.   :1.00   Length:4
>    1st Qu.:1.75   Class :character
>    Median :2.50   Mode  :character
>    Mean   :2.50
>    3rd Qu.:3.25
>    Max.   :4.00
>
> for(i in 1:nrow(st1)) { st1$z[i]= (st1$st-mean(st)/sd(st))}
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In st1$z[i] <- (st1$st - mean(st)/sd(st)) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   2: In st1$z[i] <- (st1$st - mean(st)/sd(st)) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   3: In st1$z[i] <- (st1$st - mean(st)/sd(st)) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   4: In st1$z[i] <- (st1$st - mean(st)/sd(st)) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   for(i in 1:nrow(st1)) { 
        st1$z[i]= (st1$st[i]-mean(st)/sd(st))
    }
```